# Workarounds for compilations on remote machine

Tags: compilation, installation

Recently I have been working on a remote cluster (Scientific Linux 6 operating system), where I don't have root permissions to install the libraries I need to compile my C codes.

I ran into several issues:

1) If you can't run yum to install what you need, what can you do?

2) If you can't make install, what can you do?

3) How do I run my executables (assuming I could compile them) when they might need to call on libraries not installed on the machine?

I have posted this question so I can share what I have found to work around this problem. I hope it is useful...

Answer (score 0):

Here we go!

1) **If you can't install via "yum"**, you can try

1.1) Find out what ".rpm" repository has the libraries you need (google for it).

1.2) Download the relevant ".rpm" onto your home machine.

1.3) Then scp the "rpm" repository to your remote machine - or

```
 scp repository.rpm user@remotemachine.com:/home/user
```

1.4) Then

```
ssh user@remote.com
```

There do the following (to "install" the rpm file without root permissions):

```
export ins=repository.rpm
rpm2cpio $ins | cpio -idv
```

This will unpack your rpm file, usually to a folder /home/user/usr/lib64.

1.5) You can then

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/user/usr/lib64
```

2) Instead of **"make install":**

2.1) Run

```
make install --prefix=/home/user/file
```

to "install" your libraries into /home/user/file

2.2) Then add /home/user/file to your LD library path as above.

3) **Compiling when you have the libraries in "funny" directories:**

3.1) Copy all your necessary libraries into a new directory /home/user/libs

3.2) Put this directory on LD library path i.e.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/user/libs
```

3.3) To your Makefile for your executables, add

```
$LIBDIR = /home/user/libs

LIBS = -L$(LIBDIR) -llib1 -llib2 ... -llibn
```

(where lib1...libn are the designators for your libraries (like -llapack for the LAPACK libraries for example).

Hope that helps! All the best with your remote computing and good luck!